# Reading row of listview in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I am using custom adapter for listview. In row layout contains, two EditText view & one image view. I want read value of EditText view on button action(which will be clicked at ending). When I manually write entries in edittext box, I am unable to call 'notifyDataSetChanged'. So only old values are set to adapter. Now at end, how to read current data  directly from edittext view.

Event editText.getText() also not working. It shows previous data, not modified data.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: have you tried to use addTextChangedListener? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Comment: As per my knowledge, as there is only addTextChangedListener will work. But how can I decide user has done with typing?

Comment: Really thnx you guys for taking interests.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it is fixed.
My main problem was if EditText view is edited, I need to catch that event. If i use TextWatcher, it signals only when text will be changed.(not when editing is done completely). To catch editing is done, I used dialog. So when user try to edit value from EditTextView, I show dialog with EditText. When 'Ok' will be pressed, it signal that editing is done.

And then update my value.